# Qt Creator seems to be struggling to parse Valgrind memcheck output with googletest

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt-creator, valgrind

When I run Valgrind memcheck tool from Qt Creator on my unit test project (which is using google test), I have a weird issue with the output. Qt Creator is convenient as it filters out the external errors but with my unit test project it looks like it struggles to parse the valgrind ouput. As an example, at some point in one of my tests I have the following:

```
QRegularExpression regExp(RegExpGetter::date());
ASSERT_TRUE(regExp.isValid());
EXPECT_FALSE(regExp.match(QStringLiteral("29-02-2021")).hasMatch()); 
//...
```

And while some Valgrind output is parsed correctly by Qt Creator, others (such as the output produced by my test above, but also many other tests) are displayed in the console output formatted as xml. Now, I noticed that as soon as this issue arises, the next errors are not parsed correctly but are all displayed in the console (which makes it hard -- and that's an understatement, to detect my own errors). I created some explicit memory leaks and while some in the previously ran test suites are displayed correctly, others are not but I can still find them in the console if I search for them. Here's a screenshot of the issue.
[image: issue]

I tried disabling Google Test ouput, thinking it may conflict with how Qt Creator parses the valgrind results, but it didn't help. Any idea how to solve my problem?

I am running valgrind 3.16.1 and Qt Creator 4.14.2 on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: Is the valgrind xml output directly written to `stdout`? If yes, can't it be changed to write to a file instead?

Comment: Well, the idea behind using Qt Creator was to conveniently make use of the filtered output to quickly identify my errors. So I do not want to redirect to a file (I would need, I think, to write suppression files to get rid of errors from the libraries used by the Qt framework)

Comment: I'm actually surprised that, when use use valgrind inside Qt Creator, it doesn't automatically write the output to a file.

Comment: Looking at the command invoked by Qt Creator: 
`valgrind --child-silent-after-fork=yes --xml-socket=127.0.0.1:35277 --log-socket=127.0.0.1:41797 --xml=yes --smc-check=stack --tool=memcheck --gen-suppressions=all --leak-check=summary --num-callers=25 /home/geoffrey/dev/Screeni/screeniv3/bin/debug/screeni-tests`
I cannot see the `--log-file` argument, so I do not think it's output to a file.

Comment: Doesn't `--log-socket=127.0.0.1:41797` mean that the data is sent directly to this port, which is presumably a port made available by QtCreator?